# How to call a Python script in a Django server from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, django

Salut!

I have a HTML running properly in a Django server, also I have a function in a Python file which send an e-mail. I would like to execute this function when an submit input is clicked. So, how can I call this function using JavaScript?

I've read about using AJAX, but I think that this could be code easily. Am I wrong?

Comment: AJAX exists for that purpose.

Comment: Post to server, have the function that handles the post call the python function

Answer (score 2):

Yes you're right ! 
With Django you can grab all the post that the user send and do something with these datas.

So for example in mail.html page :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %} 
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

And in views.py :

```
def send_mail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        mail = request.POST.get('mail')
        comment = request.POST.get('comment')
        # YOUR SCRIPT TO SEND MAIL HERE WITH THE VARIABLES
    else:
         return render(request, 'mail.html')
```